# Can you fix a broken tine in an electrical plug?

Tags: electrical, cord-and-plug

After years of bending, one tine in the plug on my old table saw finally snapped off:

[image]

Can this be fixed? Or would you have to buy a new plug head, or an entirely new cord and head and rewiring into the motor?

Comment: Just get a new plug.  That type of plug is not repairable.  The real problem is why are you bending it?  Plugs are straight push in/pull out and no bending needed.  If bending is needed you have a second problem that must be fixed.

Comment: To expand on crip659's comment, if you have to keep pinching or spreading the pins to use the plug in a particular outlet then it's time to replace the outlet. It's worth investing in a better grade of outlet, rather than the bargain barrel full, to get ones that maintain tension and hold plugs reliably over time.

Comment: It looks like you actually have two pins broken off, so it's probably needed a new plug or cord and plug for a while now.

Comment: @crip659: I'm not bending it intentionally, it's just gotten stepped on or had stuff dropped on it for probably 30 years. At the moment, I'm using it in a brand new outlet.

Comment: @kmj: Oh, you're right. The ground pin is gone too. Yikes.

Comment: When you put the new plug on it, make sure to wire it up as a 3-prong plug and don't bypass the safety ground.  It's there for a reason!

Comment: At least your second problem is easy to fix, just don't drop stuff or step on it.

Answer (score 3):

### Depends how you feel about molded plugs

And the length of the cord.   The local hardware store will have a retrofit plug for under $5, but you will notice they are not watertight and bugs and dirt can get in there.

However they are never quite as good as the factory-molded plug. So you can either buy an extension cord and lop off the socket end, or buy a new line cord from GALCO, Grainger or my preference, McMaster-Carr.

Be careful about the cord rating - look closely at the old cord and note wire AWG and also rating - SW, SJOOW, SJW, etc.  Look up those codes and make sure you are not downgrading yourself.

Comment: You can get better-quality replacement plugs, but you may have to skip your local hardware store (unless it's a good one) and the under $5 price point, too. "Deadfront" is a good search term, usually.

Comment: That _woosh_ sound you just heard is the "garden statuary" comment flying over my head... :(

Comment: It's a subtle political jab. Just let it go, it appears to be in good fun.

Comment: @KMJ: Well now I want to get the joke....

Comment: Based on the suggestion, I checked out McMaster-Carr and got this page: https://www.mcmaster.com/products/appliance-power-cords/length~6-ft-/

And it'll be about $10. Thanks for the idea.

In your answer, what is the difference between a "retrofit plug" and a "molded plug"?

Comment: @Ecnerwal: I did look up dead front outlets, but found it a little puzzling. I've been using regular outlets my whole life without ever seeing one with an opening to the wiring, and if I did, I wouldn't stick my fingers in there. Sealing off access like that seems like overkill, so I must not be understanding the problem that this is solving.

Comment: @JoshuaFrank SJW is an acronym for Social Justice Warriors, a form of activist.  My SJW cord would not shut up about the garden gnomes, who we peacefully coexist with :)

Comment: @JoshuaFrank  A molded plug is like the one you have now, it is molded around the wires and prongs in one piece.  It needs a knife/saw to take apart.  The replacement/retrofit plug is screwed together, so it can be taken apart and the wires connected to the prongs.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica: ah, now I get it. Thanks.

Comment: @crip659: Hmm, being accessible for repair seems like a good thing, but since this cord will probably go another 30 years and then only be 10 bucks to replace, I guess molded is better.

Comment: @Joshua that's my preference, yeah.  I had identified an 8' long cord at Target that cost very little, which I used widely for fluorescent fixtures.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica the big box stores carry them too, just make sure you get a 14 gauge one rather than a 16.

Answer (score 3):

Repair, in this case, is by replacement. You can replace just the plug, or the whole "cord and plug" for a home shop environment - some workplace environments may be required to do the "cord and plug" route.

If the saw lives in one or two locations only, you might consider investing in a NEMA L5-15 or L5-20 plug and a matching receptacle or two ("twist lock" style locking connectors) but if it's regularly hauled around to lots of different locations that may be less practical than keeping the 5-15 "standard" plug.

If it lives in your shop and is not used as a portable saw at all, it's well worth considering changing it over to 240V operation (most tablesaw motors can be wired either way) and using a suitable cord and plug and receptacle (NEMA 6-15 or L6-15) and circuit for that. That is also more difficult with a saw you haul around to different work locations.

Comment: This is a portable contractor's saw and I do move it around a lot, but one day I'd like a larger stationary one, so this is quite good to know. Thanks!